# Images cropped when todonotes and auto-pst-pdf used together in scrbook

Tags: koma-script, todonotes, auto-pst-pdf

In my document, I am required to have non-floating images in one chapter.
However, while there is no problem with images in floats, non-floating images are cropped at the bottom.
This only happens to eps-files as far as I have checked.

I have quite a big document now with lots of packages.
And was able to pin the problem down to `todonotes`, `auto-pst-pdf` and the koma-script class `scrbook`. When I deactivate either package or use `article` for example, the images are not cropped.

[image: Example Image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, parskip]{scrbook}

\usepackage[runs=2, crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{example-image.eps}
\end{figure}

\includegraphics{example-image.eps}
\end{document}
```

I definitely need `auto-pst-pdf` with the options given and the `scrbook` class.
When the document is finished, I may not need `todonotes`.
However, I am far from done and still need the package.
Also, I don't want to guess if my figures look good until I am finished.

So what can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core problem is imho the `parskip` setting. When tikz is loaded (by todonotes) a positive `\parskip` is also inserted in the preview box of the image and moves it down.

So I would suggest to do this:

```
\documentclass[12pt, parskip]{scrbook}

\usepackage[runs=2, crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\ifpdf \else \parskip=0pt\fi

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{example-image.eps}
\end{figure}

\includegraphics{example-image.eps}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `\ifpdf \fi` on the `todonotes` package works just as well and seems a bit more focused on the issue with that package. Could the `\parskip=0pt` not affect other parts of my document. What are the benefits of this approach?

Comment: Well you will have to decide if not loading a lots of packages like tikz, todonotes and so on  during the dvips run or changing one length will affect other parts of your document more.

Comment: True. In my case, `todonotes` seems to be the only package loading `tikz`. So I guess I will be fine with that. I wish I could select both answers. But while I am going with @Herbert, I will select yours as the answer, because you gave the explanation that may help others in the future.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
\documentclass[12pt, parskip]{scrbook}

\usepackage[runs=2, crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}
\ifpdf
  \usepackage{todonotes}
\fi
[...]
```

Comment: This works perfectly!
I still selected Ulrike's answer due to the explanation what causes the problem.